# Salesforce Winter ’20 LWC issue with two way binding

Tags: lightning-web-components

I know that 2 way binding worked before winter release. Unfortunately with sandboxes updates this back door was closed. So you cannot pass attribute from aura to lwc component then update it in lwc and handle changes in aura. 
Does anybody have same problems with data binding in LWC?

Comment: LWC has always been 1 way, so, what you were experiencing before was probably an exploited bug which you took for granted?
maybe you can share a minimal reproducible code sample of what used to work which doesn't anymore? as is, your question seems mostly open ended that wont have any concrete answer.

Comment: @glls +1 .. your comment should probably be answer with some example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lightning Web Components have always been 1 way as indicated in the documentation:

[Data Binding Behavior Differences With Aura](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.migrate_data_binding)

> The data binding between components for property values is one-way.
>
> To communicate down from a parent component to a child component, set a property or call a method on the child component.
>
> To communicate up from a child component to a parent component, send an event.

The update probably corrected a bug which you might had though was something that was working as expected. If you strongly feel that what you have should continue working, i'd encourage you to edit your post with a minimal reproduce-able code sample.